# Is it possible to somehow add data specific to an individual page's widget in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add a google maps widget to Pages on a Wordpress site. They all have the same Template with a Sidebar but the map will be unique for each. I feel like there should be a way to populate the widget from the edit page screen for that Page. Does each Page actually need it's own Template?

This seems limiting maybe I'm missing something. If the question is unclear I let me know but I think this should be something ppl have run up against before.

Comment: How did you get the google map.any plugin or any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the integration of a wordpress plugin to accomplish this. It will be fairly easy to do.

If you want to do this without purchasing any 'pro' versions of a plugin and don't mind writing some simple code, then I would suggest Simple Google Map. You will have to insert a shortcode into the widgetized sidebar area. Here is the plugin link - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-map/

In order to customize each page's sidebar area, You need to write some code. Please refer to this article which will explain how http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/display-different-sidebar-for-each-post-and-page-for-wordpress/

It involves a simple alteration of your 'single.php' file and the usage of 'custom fields' so that you will be able to do this from the edit screen of the page, just like you wanted to do!

Comment: thanks I'm using a custom field to hold the name of a custom side bar file with that pages map html embed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain text widget for each map and Widget Logic to select the page it appears on: [WordPress › Widget Logic « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/)